# How to create field and get data from joined table in Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm using EF6 Code First to work.
First I created 2 class:

```cs
public class Course
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}
public class Tag
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; }
}
```

After add-migration and update-database, I have 3 table Courses, Tags and TagCourses. But I dont have TagCourse class in project. How can I add new fields like Details on TagCourses and CRUD this joined table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This *might* work for you

```
public class Course
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public ICollection<TagCourse> TagCourses{ get; set; }
}

public class TagCourse
{
   public int CourseId {get;set; }
   public int TagId {get;set; }

   public string Details {get;set; }
}

public class Tag
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public ICollection<TagCourse> TagCourses { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: @HiếuNguyễnĐắc be sure to mark an answer if they have helped you, to help other people